# Can I see who checkouted or updated from a SVN repository?

Tags: svn, logging, users

is there a way to see a log where all updates and checkouts from a SVN repo are stored?
I need to know which users are updating or checkouting the contents.

Comment: What I want is to log when anyone does a "svn up", not a "svn ci"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your SVN server is fronted by an Apache server then you can find accesses that don't change the SVN database (e.g checkouts and updates which don't appear in the SVN history) in the Apache http log.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the following post at stackoverflow and adjust as needed:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955976/ever-need-to-parse-the-svn-log-for-files-committed-by-a-particular-user-since-a-c

Comment: hm... that doesn't seem to work... the normal svn log only shows commit history

Answer (score -1):

You're probably referring to [Examining History](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.tour.history.html), where the `svn log` command:

> Shows you broad information: log
>   messages with date and author
>   information attached to revisions, and
>   which paths changed in each revision.

The SVN server normally only logs updates, but it can be set to log checkouts.

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for... I want to see the updates, not the checkouts

Comment: So "svn log" is what you asked for. (I only mentioned checkouts because you did.)